# ARIMA series SAS vs R

Tags: r, sas

I am testing SAS and R with time series.

I have this code in R

ARIMA (1,1,0) (0,1,1)

```
 ar1_ma12noint<-arima(qxts, order = c(1,1,0),seasonal = list(order = c(0,1, 1), period = 12),
                     include.mean = FALSE )

ar1_ma12noint

(1-pnorm(abs(ar1_ma12noint$coef)/sqrt(diag(ar1_ma12noint$var.coef))))*2
```

And this code in SAS,

```
proc arima data= serie.diff12_r  plots(unpack)=series(corr crosscorr);
identify var=pasajeros nlag=60 ;
estimate p=(1) q=(12) noint ;
run;
```

EDIT: SPSS shows same estimate parameter than SAS.

i have same model in both of them but

R shows this estimate parameters:

```
Coefficients:
     ar1    sma1
  -0.353  -0.498
```

s.e.   0.082   0.068

And SAS,

```
 MA1,1 0.48528 0.08367 5.80 <.0001 12 
AR1,1 -0.34008 0.08666 -3.92 0.0001 1
```

I am wondering why estimate is different beetween two programs. I mean the sing for seasonal ma parameter.

thanks for all!

EDIT: i think R shows moving average model with change sing.

Question is close!

Comment: It doesn't look like you're differencing your series in SAS, but your R code is specifying a differenced series.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Your R model is using simple & seasonal differencing, whereas your SAS model is not
2. SAS uses conditional least squares estimation by default, whereas R uses conditional least squares to initialize ML estimates.

Specifying ML estimates and adding differencing of orders `(1 12)` should produce the same results:

```
proc arima data= serie.diff12_r  plots(unpack)=series(corr crosscorr);
    identify var=pasajeros(1 12) nlag=60 ;
    estimate p=(1) q=(12) noint method=ml;
run;
```